# Readability of overloaded functions

Tags: java, c#, c++, coding-style, overloading

I really hate overloaded functions especially when they are calling each other. It is really difficult to figure out who is calling whom without looking really carefully at the function signature. I came across one example that happen to be short enough to post as a question.

I'd like some comments on this.

Does anyone share my feelings?

What are the alternatives of method overloading?

For readability purposes, is only providing the version that actually does the job(ex. OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs args) and force everyone to use this single version a good idea?

```
protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

protected void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyDescriptor property)
{
    OnPropertyChanged(new TPropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
}

protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    OnPropertyChanged(new TPropertyChangedValueEventArgs(propertyName, oldValue, newValue));
}

protected void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyDescriptor property, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    OnPropertyChanged(new TPropertyChangedValueEventArgs(property, oldValue, newValue));
}

protected void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (mSuspendPropertyChanged == 0)
    {
        PropertyChanged.Raise(this, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is opinion based.

Comment: @hagrawal Yes it is opinion based. It is actually this question is for, to ask for opinions. Readability is a subjective thing. Judging whether a piece of code is easy to read or not demands survey of opinions.

Comment: Have a look at the help page that described what types of questions you _shouldn't ask_: [help/dont-ask]. You're hitting many of the bullets on that page.

Answer (score 1):

At my work, we have an extremely large C++ application.  This is one of my pet peeves because it is very difficult to search the code base and determine if a refactoring is safe.  Whenever possible, if I need to work on code and there are overloaded functions, I'll simply rename the function something longer (maybe *OnPropertyChanged_uses_object_args*).  Then, let the compiler help you (if it is C++).  Once you have the application built and successfully linking, you can do your refactoring much more easily.

Of course, this doesn't work with late-bound languages.  If that's the case, instead you need a good function browser that works with overloads.  Most good IDE's have one.